Flutter widget not immediately rerendering with setState
I want to create a custom PopupMenuButton that would contain special menu items that can trigger expand/collapse to see more or less menu items.
The feature of expand/collapse work as shown in the picture, but there is mismatch and I have to close the popup menu and reopen it in order it to be updated. How can I update the popup menu without having to close/re-open it?
All the code is available here
And the bug is shown in the picture below.

